Combining Measures from different Tables
I'm currently building a dashboard that consist of data sources with multiple level of relationship. Some of the tables do not communicate with each other and do not have a relationship that I can combine.
Table Relationship
What I'm trying to achieve is to combine all 3 measures into 1 table. Ideally, the intended calculated measure I'm looking for is to get something like this.
Overall Yield = Yield A (From Table A) * Yield B (From Table B) * Yield C (From Table C).
I tried to create a relationship across the 3 tables but as they don't talk to each other, the results being shown over is not correct and is showing one single value across day, week & month. I also tried to play around by linking the 3 tables into a master calendar table and putting the combined measure there, but it's not working as well. My thought process here is to combine the 3 measures into 1 and store this combined measure in a calendar table so that I can use the Date from Calendar table as the main Date column. However, I'm not really sure how I can navigate this, and this is where I'm stuck at.
The expected output I'm expecting to retrieve from my data source is something like this.
Output

Link to my test data source and power BI working file: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AiNw1b4HnMZOgaBb0fIaKLkRaAnuEA
Appreciate the help and support! Thanks!

what's the expected output based on the sample data you provided?

I have edited the post to include the expected output. Many thanks!

pls modify your measures
Yield A Formula =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Yield A'[FINISHQTY] ),
    FILTER (
        'Yield A',
        'Yield A'[Week Number] = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Week Number] )
    )
)
    / CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Yield A'[STARTQTY] ),
        FILTER (
            'Yield A',
            'Yield A'[Week Number] = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Week Number] )
        )
    )


Yield B Formula =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Yield B'[FINISHQTY] ),
    FILTER (
        'Yield B',
        'Yield B'[Week Number] = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Week Number] )
    )
)
    / CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Yield B'[STARTQTY] ),
        FILTER (
            'Yield B',
            'Yield B'[Week Number] = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Week Number] )
        )
    )

NEW START QTY =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Yield C'[NEW FINISH QTY] ),
    FILTER (
        'Yield C',
        'Yield C'[Week Number] = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Week Number] )
    )
)
    + CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Yield C'[BNU Qty] ),
        FILTER (
            'Yield C',
            'Yield C'[Week Number] = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Week Number] )
        )
    )

Yield C Formula =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Yield C'[NEW FINISH QTY] ),
    FILTER (
        'Yield C',
        'Yield C'[Week Number] = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Week Number] )
    )
) / [NEW START QTY]

then create a new measure
MEASURE =
VAR _a =
    IF ( ISBLANK ( 'Yield A'[Yield A Formula] ), 1, 'Yield A'[Yield A Formula] )
VAR _b =
    IF ( ISBLANK ( 'Yield B'[Yield B Formula] ), 1, 'Yield B'[Yield B Formula] )
VAR _c =
    IF ( ISBLANK ( 'Yield C'[Yield C Formula] ), 1, 'Yield C'[Yield C Formula] )
RETURN
    _a * _b * _c


